# AngularJs naming convention uppercase letter for controller

Tags: angularjs

why in AngularJs name conventions, the name of a controller should begin with uppercase letter while others seem to begin with lowercase letter?

Comment: could you go through this https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to name classes with uppercase first letter to distinguish them from simple functions. Since Angular controllers are technically constructor functions which construct new controller instance objects - for consistency it is better to reflect this fact in the name too.

On the other hand, injectable services are not constructors, they are already objects (created behind the scene), so there is no need to name them with uppercase - they are not constructors you are (or Angular) going to use to create new object instances with `new` keyword.

But of course, this is just a convention, not very strict. Just a nice consistency.